# Check if content in entry has changed

Tags: plugin-development, entries

Is there a simple way to know if an entry's content changed when it was saved?

I'm pulling data from an XML feed and create/update entries in a section. I need to know which entries has new data. I guess I could check each field value individually, or make some kind of hash and check that. But is there some built-in way in Yii/Craft that is easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's currently anything in Craft that's going to help you here.

Ideally we'd track for dirty/changed fields in JavaScript on an edit entry page and pass that as a parameter into the `onBeforeSaveEntry` event.

Comment: Ok, I'll just have to write my own isDirty(). :)

Comment: Cool... I think your hash idea is the way I'd try first. :)